# sprite.SetScale Function not working (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

Hello i'm trying to make a simple game with libGDX but i'm running with some trouble using the sprite class, this is my code:

```
package com.carebearer;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class demo extends ApplicationAdapter{
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    Sprite sprite;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("hello.png"); 
        sprite = new Sprite(img);
        sprite.setScale(.5f);
        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - sprite.getWidth()/2, 
                           Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); //RGBAlpha, 1 = 100%
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY()); 
        batch.end();
    } 
   }
```

The problem is the setScale function.

Whether or not i use setScale the sprite drawn stays the same (It's essentially doing nothing). What i want it to do is to halve in size the Sprite

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something obvious but i've been stuck with this problem more time than i would like to admit.

Comment: Ok after hours of trying i managed to find my mistake after a few minutes of posting this. In order for the scaling to work you need to send it to batch.draw because it appears that if you do not indicate it, the function will take the image original scale as a default. Here are the changes made to the code. > batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(),sprite.getWidth()/2,sprite.getHeight()/2,sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight(),sprite.getScaleX(),sprite.getScaleY(),sprite.getRotation());

Comment: Or use the sprite to draw itself with the help of the batch. `sprite.draw(batch)` which is the intended way of drawing sprites.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using Sprite correctly. Use `sprite.draw(batch)` not `batch.draw(sprite, ...)`. If you use `batch.draw` then SpriteBatch treats Sprite like a dumb TextureRegion and ignores all its position and size parameters. And if you manually apply them like you did in your comment, you might as well use the much lighter weight TextureRegion instead of SpriteBatch.